# Get Error : The 'Id' property on 'Match' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I got this error :

> The 'Id' property on 'Match' could not be set to a 'System.Int32'
>   value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type
>   'System.Int64'. "

With a code snippet like:

```
Match _match =_entities.Match.SingleOrDefualt(match => match.Id == MatchId);
```

It happened sometimes not all the time and I check the type of my poco class with Database and it's correct!
I Use `EF 6.1.3` code first. I'm Confused!

My entity class is:

```
[Table("Match")]
public class Match
{
    public Match()
    {
        Hands = new HashSet<Hand>();
        Rounds = new HashSet<Round>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public long FirstPlayerId { get; set; }

    public byte FirstPlayerRedrawHandCount { get; set; }

    public long? SecondPlayerId { get; set; }

    public byte SecondPlayerRedrawHandCount { get; set; }

    public byte SpeedType { get; set; }

    public MatchType MatchType { get; set; }

    public byte FirstPlayerScore { get; set; }

    public byte SecondPlayerScore { get; set; }

    public MatchStatus Status { get; set; }

    public long? DCUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime? RetryTime { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public RegisterState RegisterState { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FirstPlayerId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SecondPlayerId")]
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Hand> Hands { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Round> Rounds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `MatchId` in `Match _match =_entities.Match.SingleOrDefualt(match => match.Id == MatchId);`?  Where does that come from?  Show more of your code.

Comment: Maybe `match.Id == Convert.ToInt64(MatchId)`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, this is not the problem. The error message is about an assign, not a comparison. The problem must be when the entity tries to put the data on the table in the instance of Match.

Comment: @roryap it's parameter of function and i said that it's long too

Comment: @Jauch I check this more and more and all thing seems fine and both side of DB and Poco class is same and i mentioned that this error apear sometimes not all the time

Comment: Which is this 'poco' class you are mentioning? Is the Match class?

Comment: @Jauch ya it's  Match Class

Comment: Do you have found the problem, Hamed? :)

Answer (score 1):

From the message, almost sure your table has an Id of type System.int32 (int), and your class has a type of system.int64 (long).

Change the Match.Id to int, if the database field is int (what must be the case here).

Comment: I mentioned that both database column and class type is long(big int)

Comment: Indeed. But the error is that you are trying to assing an int to a long. If the error is on the line you showed, só you havê a long in the matxh classe that is an int in the database. Which database are you using? SQL server?

Comment: ya i use Sql Server 2014 and i should say again that it's happend some times and i confused

Comment: If you change the id in the class to int, what happens? Just to test it.

Comment: I don't do that yet- but i should say sometimes it's happened to other field of this class too, i think it's problem of EF mapper

Comment: OK. Do you realize EF is ou there for quite some time and it is unlikely to have this kind of issue. It's not impossible, of course.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Nikhil Agrawal, Convert your MatchId to ToInt64

```
Match _match =_entities.Match.SingleOrDefualt(match => match.Id == Convert.ToInt64(MatchId));
```

As in .net, long and Int64 are same

Comment: MatchId is long! should i convert it again?